# how to read an array in one proc to another proc as proc are in same namespace

Tags: tcl

```
namespace eval ::content {
    variable nettopin
    array unset nettopin
    namespace export display show
}

proc content::display { } {
    array unset nettopin
    set filename "net.txt"
    set fh [open $filename r]

    while {[gets $fh data] >= 0} {
        if {$data ne ""} {
            set net [lindex $data 1]
            set pin [lindex $data 0]
            if { ![info exists nettopin($net)] } {
                set nettopin($net) "$pin"
                puts $nettopin($net)
            } else {
                set lastnet $net
                set newpin $pin
                lappend nettopin($lastnet) $newpin
            }
        }
    }
    parray nettopin
}

content::display

#################################

proc content::show {net} {
    variable nettopin 
    array unset nettopin
    puts "$nettopin($net)"
}

content::show GNDP
```

in proc show i am getting error can't able to read array nettopin

Comment: Why are you unsetting the array before `puts`-ing it?

Comment: no just neglect that line of code

Answer (score 2):

The `content::display` needs to have:

```
variable nettopin
```

in it or it will work with a *local* variable with that name, and not a *namespace* variable with that name.

And doing `array unset nettopin` immediately before using it is extremely unlikely to be a good idea; that deletes the array…

Comment: Putting `variable nettopin` in the `namespace eval` is a good idea anyway for reasons that don't matter for this question, but it _also_ needs to be inside each procedure that uses it.